# How to hide the already selected value from the dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to hide **already selected value** from the dropdown list.

For example, I have the dropdown with 2 options:

- Cancelled
- Confirmed

[image: dropdown]

If user select the "Cancelled" option - the dropdown list shouldn't contain the selected option. In this case the only one 'Confirm' option should be available in the dropdown list.

If user select "Confirm" option - the dropdown should contain the only one "Cancelled" option.

In other words - I need to **display selected value in the `select`** (for example 'Cancelled'), **but doesn't display this value in the dropdown list** (dropdown will contain the only 'Confirmed' value).

The question is - is it possible to implement, and if yes - how?

I'm using AngularJS on my frontend side.

```
<select ng-options="status.id as status.name for status in appt.possibleStatuses" 
   ng-model="appt.statusId">
</select>
```

I understand, that it's possible to implement with custom UI control, but I want to do it via default `select` tag.

But if you know easy and nice solutions for this problem without using of the `select` tag - you are welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: I know it's sort of a _"hack"_, but an additional blank option at the top has always suited me fine, just ensure you add logic to catch the null submission.

Comment: @MichaelWiggins, Could you please provide example in the answer?

Comment: Dimitry summs this up pretty well I feel

Comment: @MichaelWiggins. No these answers is not what I want, please, check my updated question once more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function instead of `appt.possibleStatuses`

```
<select ng-options="status.id as status.name for status in filterFunction()" 
   ng-model="appt.statusId">
</select>
```

And in your controller code

```
$scope.filterFunction = function () {
    var statuses = $scope.appt.possibleStatuses;
    // any custom filter logic for statuses
    return statuses;
}
```

Comment: No. This doesn't resolve my problem. I need to remove from list the same option which I've selected. The question - is it possible to implement. After some attempts I think - no.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to my *"hack"* method mentioned in the question comments, you could implement something like this:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
  <select name="value_Name">
     <option value="" selected></option>
     <option value="value1">value1</option>
     <option value="value2">value2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The "selected" tag informs the browser that this is the default value. You can then implement any means of input validation you wish.

Personally, I prefer to do everything at a servlet-level but you can implement this via JQuery or JavaScript functions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `ng-change="changeFunction(appt.statusId)"` like

```
<select ng-options="status.id as status.name for status in appt.possibleStatuses" ng-model="appt.statusId" ng-change="changeFunction(appt.statusId)">
```

Put bellow js code in your controller

```
$scope.changeFunction = function(status){
    if(status == "Cancelled"){
        /* code for hide or remove "Confirm" option */
    } else if(status == "Confirm"){
        /* code for hide or remove "Cancelled" option */
    }
}
```

Comment: No. In your case I need to hide/remove the same option with selected. If I select "Cancelled" - I nned to hide "Cancelled" option from the options.

Comment: Then you can use splice() method in given if else condition for remove selected option

Comment: Did you tested that? I'm sure that - no. If you remove currently selected value from the list of the options, it also dissapears from the displayed value.